# Shell: How to stop a command line if it times out？

Tags: shell, apache-spark

I want to stop the command if it run more than 1 minutes and continue run the next command.

```
for((part=0;part<=100;part++)); 
do
spark-submit \
--verbose \
--master yarn  \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.pyspark.python=myenv/bin/python3 \
python_demo.py $part
done
```

The command `spark-submit` will submit my code to yarn. After submitting successfully, it'll run until the code `ython_demo.py` stops. But now I want to the continue to submit if one is submitted successfully.

Now the shell run like :

```
spark-submit -> submit successfully （about 1 minutes)-> run python_demo.py(it will run for a long time) -> spark-submit next part
```

Expected:

```
spark-submit -> if run more than 1 minutes(It means a successful submission)-> spark-submit next part
```

Comment: Ever heard about `timeout` utility? Look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With timeout command you can do something like this:

```
for((part=1;part<=100;part++))
do
    timeout 60 2>/dev/null spark-submit \
    --verbose \
    --master yarn  \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.pyspark.python=myenv/bin/python3 \
    python_demo.py $part

    if [[ $? != 0 ]]
    then
        break
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```